# Azure databricks cluster local storage maximum size

Tags: azure-databricks

I am having a databrick cluster on Azure,
there is a local storage /mnt /tmp /user..
May I know are there any folder size limitation for each of the folder ?
And how long the data will be retention ?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028296/what-is-the-data-size-limit-of-dbfs-in-azure-databricks

Answer (score 0):

Databricks File System (DBFS) is a distributed file system mounted into an Azure Databricks workspace and available on Azure Databricks clusters. DBFS is an abstraction on top of scalable object storage i.e. ADLS gen2.

> There is no restriction on the amount of data you can store in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

**Note:** Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 able to store and serve **many exabytes of data.**

> **For Azure Databricks Filesystem (DBFS)** - Support only files less than **2GB** in size.

**Note:** If you use local file I/O APIs to read or write files larger than 2GB you might see corrupted files. Instead, access files larger than 2GB using the DBFS CLI, dbutils.fs, or Spark APIs or use the /dbfs/ml folder.

> **For Azure Storage** – Maximum storage account capacity is **5 PiB** Petabytes.

For more details, refer [What is the Data size limit of DBFS in Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028296/what-is-the-data-size-limit-of-dbfs-in-azure-databricks).